# Path dependence of integrals

Tags: complex-analysis

Are the integrals of the function

$ \Large f(z)=e^{1/z}dz$ path independent in the domain $D= \{Re z >0\}\setminus\{3\}$?

Comment: $e^{1/z}$ is analytic in the right half plane. Do you know Cauchy's Thm?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the right-half plane is simply connected, $f$ is holomorphic on the right half plane and so any contour integral along a closed path in the right half plane evaluates to $0$ by Cauchy's integral theorem. This includes closed paths in $D \subset \{Re(z) > 0\}$. Now think what happens if two paths share the same endpoints.